# Converting base64 String to JSON String and Sent to REST API using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, rest, base64

I am using AngularJS, HTML 5, JavaScript and Rest API to upload an image in database.
The back-end is made on Hibernate and it is working perfectly.
The image is being converted to base64 String and then it is being send to Rest API.
The problem is that the image is being uploaded in the database but there is an error showing in the console. 
Here is he code

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload/master/src/angular-base64-upload.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="pic" ng-controller="MainController">
    <input type="file" ng-model="image" base-sixty-four-input>
    <button ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
    <div ng-bind="message"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main JS File

```
URI = "http://localhost:8085/PictureUpload/api/";

var app = angular.module('pic', [ 'naif.base64' ])

app.controller("MainController", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.image = {};
    $scope.upload = function() {
        try {
            var data = angular.toJson($scope.image.base64);
            console.log(data)
            var responsePromise = $http.post(URI + "PictureAPI",data);
        } catch (err) {
            $scope.message = "There is some system Issue, Please contact Administrator";
        }
        responsePromise.success(function(dataFromServer,
                status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message=dataFromServer;
            console.log($scope.message)
        });
        responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers,
                config) {
        });
    }
} ])
```

API File

```
package com.pic.API;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.pic.DAO.PictureDAO;
import com.pic.resources.AppConfig;

@Path("/PictureAPI")
public class PictureAPI {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response saveImage(String dataRecieved) {
        System.out.println(dataRecieved);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Response returnValue = null;
        byte[] image = Base64.decodeBase64(dataRecieved);
        System.out.println(image);
        PictureDAO pd = new PictureDAO();
        try {
            pd.savePicture(image);
            String value = "Photo Uploaded";
            returnValue = Response.ok(value).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String message = AppConfig.PROPERTIES.getProperty(e.getMessage());
            String value = gson.toJson(message);
            if (e.getMessage().contains("DAO")) {
                returnValue = Response.status(Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity(value).build();
            } else {
                returnValue = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(value)
                        .build();
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Error in Console.

```
angular.js:13642 SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0
    at wc (angular.js:1352)
    at dc (angular.js:10455)
    at angular.js:10546
    at q (angular.js:322)
    at gd (angular.js:10545)
    at c (angular.js:11343)
    at angular.js:16104
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17191)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17486)
```

Comment: String value = "Photo Uploaded";

This is what is sent to JSON instead of the base64 data. That is why unexpected token P is found at position 0

Comment: Thanks, it was a very silly mistake.

Comment: You're welcome - please mark my comments useful if they were...